# Find :: outside of markdown code formatting

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a bunch of markdown files, where I want to search for Ruby's double colon `::` outside of some code formatting (e.g. where I forgot to apply proper markdown). For example

````
`foo::bar`

hello `foo::bar` test
`  example::with::whitespace  `

```
Proper::Formatted
```

```
  Module::WithIndendation
```

```
Some::Nested::Modules
```

```ruby
CodeBlock::WithSyntax
```

# Some::Class

## Another::Class Heading
some text
````

The regex only should match `Some::Class` and `Another::Class`, because they miss the surrounding backticks, and are also not within a multiline code fence block.

I have this regex, but it also matches the multi line block

```
[\s]+[^`]+(::)[^`]+[\s]?
```

Any idea, how to exclude this?

EDIT:
It would be great, if the regex would work in Ruby, JS and on the command line for `grep`.

Comment: And you're trying this regex in ruby itself?

Comment: Are you replacing, extracting, or splitting the matches? Why do you capture the  `::`?

Comment: In ruby you can try this regex: `(?<!\`\s)(?<!\`)\b\w+::\w+`

Comment: It would be awesome, if the regex would work in Ruby, JS and on the command line with `grep`

Comment: I'm capturing `::` as an indicator that I missed a markdown formatting; in a lot of the markdown files, there is just plain text with ActiveRecord::Base or MyModule::MyClass and I'd like to find the occurrences so that I can fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *original input*, you may use this regex in ruby to match `::` string

1. not preceded by a `` ` `` and
2. not preceded by `` ` `` followed a white-space:

Regex:

```bash
(?<!`\s)(?<!`)\b\w+::\w+
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://rubular.com/r/ikQvlpdBsMQ0Yy)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<!`\s)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that <code>` and whitespace is not at preceding position
- `(?<!`)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that <code>` is not at preceding position
- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `::`: Match a `::`
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters

---

You can use this regex in Javascript:

```bash
(?<!`\w*\s*|::)\b\w+(?:::\w+)+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/5gpQZd/2)

---

For `gnu-grep`, consider this command:

```bash
grep -ZzoP '`\w*\s*\b\w+::\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\w+::\w+' file |
xargs -0 printf '%s\n'

Some::Class
Another::Class
```

[RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/5gpQZd/3)

Answer (score 1):

One can use the regular expression

```
rgx = /`[^`]*`|([^`\r\n]*::[^`\r\n]*)/
```

with the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument and no block, and therefore returns an enumerator (`str` holding the example string given in the question):

```
  str.gsub(rgx).select { $1 }
  #=> ["# Some::Class", "## Another::Class Heading"]
```

---

The idea is that the first part of the regex's alternation, `` `[^`]*` ``, matches, but *does not capture*, all strings delimited by backtics (including ``` `` ```), whereas the second part, `` ([^`\r\n]*::[^`\r\n]*) ``, matches *and captures* all strings on a single line that contain `'::'` but no backtics. We therefore concern ourselves with captures only, by invoking `select { $1 }` on the enumerator returned by `gsub`.

---

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*.

```
rgx = /
        `            # match a backtic
        [^`]*        # match zero of more characters other than backtics 
        `            # match a backtic
      |              # or
        (            # begin capture group 1
          [^`\r\n]*  # match zero of more characters other than backtics and
                     # line terminators
          ::         # match two colons
          [^`\r\n]*  # ditto line before previous
        )            # end capture group 1
      /x             # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`` [^`\r\n] `` contains `\r` (carriage return) in the event that the file was created with Windows. If desired, `` [^`]* `` can be replaced with `.*?` (match zero or more characters, as few as possible).